# Display keyboard keys with a border in Word?

Tags: macos, fonts, microsoft-word-2011

I'm writing a tutorial in Microsoft Word 2011 (Mac-version) and got a lot of keyboard-shortcuts I'm pointing to in this tutorial. I would like to display each key inline with a black border surrounding it to make it visible more clear.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply adding borders, why not use a keyboard font such as **Mac Key Caps**?

[image: 1]

You can get it [here](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Mac+Key+Caps/) or [here](http://www.fontpark.net/en/font/mac-key-caps/).

Comment: perfect! That's exactly what I've been looking for.